# Set up import aliases in Gatsby / Typescript project

Tags: typescript, gatsby, eslint-config-airbnb, typescript-eslintparser

I try to create import aliases in my Gatsby and Typescript project. I use npm package [eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias).

So I am able to use:

```
import Layout from '@components/Layout';
```

In `gatsby-node.js` I have:

const path = require('path');

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        @components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        @static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
      },
    },
  });
};
```

In `.eslintrc.js` I have:

```
alias: [['@components', './src/components']]
```

In I have:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["/components"]
```

Now I get this error in VSCode:

> Unable to resolve path to module
> 'components/layout'.eslintimport/no-unresolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding `paths: ['./src'],` to `import/resolver` inside `.eslintrc.js`:

```
'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        paths: ['./src'],
      },
      alias: [['components', './src/components']],
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need  `gatsby-plugin-resolve-src` to allow imports from `/src`. By default, it's handled by Gatsby. Everything that it's inside the project's folder it's importable as a React component if it's properly exported.

If you want to add aliasing in your imports, multiple relativity of the paths in order to avoid something like:

```
import Subscribe from '../../../../../../../core/modules/newsletter/mixins/Subscribe'
```

You can simply change your webpack's configuration by adding [`setWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#setWebpackConfig) API (in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, `src`), `node_modules`],
    },
  });
};
```

Additionally, you can add:

```
const path = require("path");
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
        "@static": path.resolve(__dirname, "static")
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The first snippet will allow you to make dynamic imports from `node_modules` and the second one in your `/components` folder.

To resolve the ESlint import, you need to install `eslint-import-resolver-alias` plugin by:

```
npm i -D eslint-import-resolver-alias
```

And then add the following configuration in your `.eslint` file:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": [
        ["@components", "./src/components"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You may find [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-set-up-import-aliases-for-gatsby-32398ae67e7f) helpful.